# How to destroy a resource after it has been used

Tags: anylogic

I've been trying to find a way to destroy a resource after the task it has been seized for has been completed, but I could not do it.
I'm following the Nurse-Ultrasound example in the AnyLogic Help, so for example I have a moving resource (worker) which seizes another resource (portable, say a box or something like that), and when the worker is done with the task I want the box to be destroyed (possibly when the worker is released). Note that I don't want the worker to go back to the box initial position.
I add a picture of what I've done, the whole resourceTaskEnd thing it's not working though.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6WU8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understand... but try this on the "on release" action of the resourcePool:

```
self.set_capacity(self.capacity-1);
```

and in the resourcePool properties, destroy units when capacity decreases...

[image: destroy units]

Comment: I'll try. Meanwhile I somewhat solved the issue making the resource invisible when idle. I also tried typing "myResource.jumpTo(homeLocation)" in the on release action of the resource pool...it doesn't work and I guess the reason is that the resource is "portable" and not "moving".